# Python: Duplicates in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, list-comprehension

Im trying to create a new list of unique values and remove said values from the original list so that what's left is duplicates. It appears my for loop is skipping over values.

```py
array = [1,3,4,2,2,3,4]
def duplicates(array):
    mylist = []
    for item in array:
        if item not in mylist:
            mylist.append(item)
            array.remove(item)
    return mylist
```

results:

> duplicates(array)

[1, 4, 2]

Comment: do you need the duplicated values or unique values? its kind of confusing

Comment: I would like to end up with a list of unique values and have the original list contain the remaining duplicate values.

Comment: can you edit your question to include the results that you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

I think that using `collections.Counter` is more appropriate for this task:

```
array = [1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4]

from collections import Counter

def duplicates(array):
  return [n for n, c in Counter(array).items() if c > 1]

print(duplicates(array))
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `array.remove(item)`, it is deleting the element at the index position visited. So, index number reduces by one and making the loop to skip reading the next value.

`[1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4]` -> before 1st iteration index 0 -> value =1

`[3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4]` -> After 1st iteration 1 is removed, so index 0 -> value =3(loop not reading it as it already read index 0, so loop is reading index 1 -> value 4)

Correct code to display values without duplicates:

```py
array = [1,3,4,2,2,3,4]

def duplicates(array):
    mylist = []
    for item in array:
        if item not in mylist:
            mylist.append(item)
            #array.remove(item)
    return mylist

res=duplicates(array)
print (res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing values from the list you are iterating through, so your loop is skipping values, try this

```py
array = [1,3,4,2,2,3,4]
def duplicates(array):
    mylist = []
    for i, item in enumerate(array):
        if item not in mylist:
            mylist.append(item)
            array[i] = None

    array[:] = list(filter(
        lambda x: x is not None,
        array
    ))

    return mylist
```

Though you should clarify what you want to do with array variable as it is currently unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a loop, it is much clearer to use a list comprehension

`dups = list(set([l for l in array if array.count(l) > 1]))`

However, the answer provided by kuco 23 does this appropriately with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [1,3,4,2,2,3,4]
def duplicates(array):
    mylist = []
    for item in array:
        if item not in mylist:
            mylist.append(item)
            array.remove(item)
        else:
            array.remove(item)
    return mylist
```

just remove the item that you don't append

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear what result you expect. If you want to get all unique values while maintaining order of occurrence, the canonical way to achieve this would be to use a `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def duplicates(array):
    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(array))

>>> duplicates(array)
[1, 3, 4, 2]
```

If you want get a list of *only* duplicates, i.e. values that occur more than once, you could use a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def duplicates(array):
    return [k for k, v in Counter(array).items() if v > 1]

>>> duplicates(array)
[3, 4, 2]
```